# map between finite and infinite vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am sorry for this basic question:
let We have two vector spaces such that one of them is finite dimensional and another one is infinte dimensional. I want to know whether I can define a linear map between them? I want to take a finite basis for infinite dimensional vector space and then define the map.

Comment: An infinite dimensional vector space does not have a finite basis.  If a finite number of elements is a basis for a vector space, then the span of those elements is the whole space, and they are all linearly independent.  But that means the dimension of the vector space is the number of elements in the basis, which would make the space finite dimensional.

Comment: It makes no sense "to take a finite basis for infinite dimensional vector space".

Comment: But if we consider the ring of polynomials with n variables with coefficients in F as an field, then we can consider that as a infinite dimensional vector space over F and we can find finitly generate set for that. isn't it?

Comment: What finite basis do you have in mind for the vector space of polynomials over a field?

Comment: Let T^n={x_1^a1...x_n^an; (a1,...,an) are in N with {0}}.

Comment: That doesn't look finite to me. It contains $x_1$, and $x_1^2$, and $x_1^3$, and so on, and so on, and so on. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment you make, you have to put @Gerry in it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you surely can. But linear maps correspond to matrices only if the corresponding vector spaces are finite dimensional.

And no, you cannot take a finite basis for an infinite dimensional vector space, but you can choose finitely many linearly independent vectors and extend them to a basis (using zorns lemma or something, to prove this extension existence) and define the map on those finitely many vectors by some image and define the map to be zero on the other vectors. you also can define the image for an infinite basis in general (in particular this is done above).

Comment: In addition I have one more question: If we have a finite vector space like V and an infinite vector space like W and we make a map as you have explained, and we have a set of vectors in V, how can we prove that a given set is linearly independent through a map between these two kind of vector spaces?

Comment: generally if you have a linear map $\psi: W \to V$, if the vectors $\psi(w_1) ,\cdots, \psi(w_n) \in V$ are linearly independent, then so are $w_1,\cdots,w_n$. This holds since:

suppose there are $\lambda_i$ such that $\sum_i \lambda_i w_i = 0$ then by linearity this yields $\psi(\sum_i \lambda_i w_i)= \sum_i \lambda_i \psi(w_i)=0$.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that we take two different vector spaces such that one of them is finite dimensional and another one is infinte dimensional. right?

Comment: in which sense? I don't really know what you mean. Here are the facts: 1) to define a linear map between two vector spaces, it suffices to define them on a basis. 2) my first comment about linear independence holds always. (note that the other direction is wrong, since linear independent vector may have the same (or more general linear dependent) images.

Answer (score 0):

More or less by definition, an infinite dimensional space has no finite bases, so the last sentence is problematic. You can still talk about bases though; see e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29#Related_notions).

As far as constructing a map is concerned, you could always take the map that maps everything to $0$. That's certainly a linear map. Perhaps you want to cook up an injective one?

Comment: I want to establish a bijection between them?

Comment: That's impossible; bijective linear operators (linear isomorphisms) preserve dimension: if you had such a map, it would take a basis of the finite dimensional space (which is finite) to a basis of the other space, but as people have pointed out, infinite dimensional spaces can not have finite bases.